# Finding the root of an equation using iteration

Tags: matlab, loops, iteration, equation-solving

I am attempting to find the root of the equation 3x<sup>3</sup>+x<sup>2</sup>-10 using iteration. Here is the code that I have so far, however I don't think I have implemented the while loop correctly since it the equation is currently only evaluated once. Essentially, the code ought to evaluate whether the absolute value of `xVal-cVal` is less than 0.0001 and if so, it should print out the value of `cVal` and stop. Otherwise, the value of `xVal` should be set to equal `cVal` and loop back, however the code does not do this.

```
xVal = input('Enter a value for x:');
cVal =((10-xVal^2)/3)^(1/3);
while (abs(xVal-cVal)>0.0001)
   xVal = cVal;
end
disp(cVal);
```

[image: Image of flowchart for equation]

Comment: You need to evaluate a new `cVal` inside the loop after assigning the old value to `xVal`. If Matlab has a do-while or do-until, that would be the ideal construct.

Comment: So while (abs(xVal-cVal)>0.0001)
        xVal = cVal; cVal =0;   
end

Comment: No, 0 isn't the correct new value for `cVal`. Think about it and don't just guess. That would just infinitely loop and test a value of 0. It needs to be computed as done the first time.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the algorithm/formula you used?

Comment: I don't have a link I'm afraid - I just rearranged the equation 3x^3+x^2-10 to make x the subject so x_(n+1)=∛((10-x^2)/3)

Comment: I doubt that this works because one of the xs remains on the right side of the equation, so you act as if they were different numbers. Consider implementing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method.

Comment: You have an equation with two x-es and you solve for one of them? That is not how root finding works. The two x-es have the same value! I would recommend you start implementing [the bisection medthod](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method), and look for more complex methods after.

Comment: I've added a link to an image of the flowchart that I'm trying to implement if that's of any help?

Comment: To implement that flow chart, you need to recompute `cVal`. But I’m not certain that it necessarily converges. Is this your algorithm or did you get it from somewhere?

Comment: I will confirm that this fixed-point iteration converges if implemented correctly (i.e., `cVal` is updated within the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

The methodology in the provided flowchart image will not work.

Try this script:

```
func = @(xVal)((10-xVal^2)/3)^(1/3);
x = fzero(func,StratingX)
```

Comment: The methodology in the flow chart will work. It's a simple fixed point iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update `cVal` in your while loop.

```
xVal = input('Enter a value for x:');
cVal =((10-xVal^2)/3)^(1/3);
while (abs(xVal-cVal)>0.0001)
   xVal = cVal;
   cVal =((10-xVal^2)/3)^(1/3);
end 
disp(cVal);
```

Output:

```
Enter a value for x:0
    1.3905
```